# Text recognition from PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, nlp

I want to write a code that loads a PDF file, converts its text to string and finds certain information within it. There are hundreds of these PDF files and each contain a certain non-tabular piece of information that I am interested in. Let's say each PDF file belongs to specific individuals that contain their address, name, age, and income. However, these PDF files do not contain this data in a consistent format. PDF1 might say "Mike's income is $100,000" while PDF2 says "Jane's salary: $110,000" and PDF3 says "Andy makes $70,000". I want to extract the salary from different PDF files and convert them to a nice panda data frame and I do not know where to begin. Can I use NLP for this? Any guidance can help me do more educated search. Thank you!

I have authored the code below to read PDF files.

I have done the following so far and it is working just fine.

```
#! pip install PyPDF2

import PyPDF2 as pdf

file = open ('File April 17th.pdf','rb')

pdf_reader = pdf.PdfReader(file)

Text = ''

for i in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    page = pdf_reader.pages[i]
    text = page.extract_text()
    Text = Text + text
```

Comment: You could look at [this](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/text-extraction/lookup-keywords.py) script to see an example of key-value text extraction.